# performance issues when running IQueryable.First()

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am making a program for a university that grabs active students and then spits out a report for other processes to use.

One of the important functions is to see if a student has graduated or not.

- If a Student graduated and is not coming back, they are not considered an active student.
- If they graduated and are coming back or didn't graduate and are coming back for another semester, they are considered active.

When a student passes through the main function, it takes about 5 seconds to run it through the process. I found that the most time taking part of the process comes from an `IQueryable.First()` in this function.

```
public static bool ContinuingEducation(string v)
{
    var TERMSSTU = from t in _DB.TERMs
                        join stu in _DB.STUDENT_TERMS_VIEWs
                        on t.TERMS_ID equals stu.STTR_TERM
                        where v == stu.STTR_STUDENT
                        orderby t.TERM_START_DATE descending
                        select new { startdate = t.TERM_START_DATE };
    var graduation = from a in _DB.ACAD_CREDENTIALs
                         where v == a.ACAD_PERSON_ID
                         orderby a.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE ascending
                         select a;

    if (graduation.Count() > 0 && TERMSSTU.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (TERMSSTU.First().startdate > graduation.First().ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE) // the problem is here
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I do not know why it takes so long here. Is there a better way to write out this function so it is faster?

Comment: You're running 4 queries.  2 for doing counts and then 2 more to get the first row of each query.  Instead just use `FirstOrDefault` and check if the results are `null` to determine if there was more than one.

Comment: Did you solve your issue Franco?

Comment: I posted my solution down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet to get some serious efficiency was to query those records in the beginning of my program so all the records are in memory which made querying a breeze for the program.

1. **I made a new class that captures those two queries**

   public class TERMSTU
   {
     public DateTime? startdate { get; set; }
     public String Id { get; set; }
   }

   public class Graduation
       {
           public DateTime? ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE { get; set; }
           public String Id { get; set; }
       }
   public class Report
   {
       private List TERMSSTUS;
       private List GRADUATIONS;
       public Report(ColleagueDataContext _DB)
       {
           var TERMSSTU = from t in _DB.TERMs
                          join stu in _DB.STUDENT_TERMS_VIEWs
                          on t.TERMS_ID equals stu.STTR_TERM
                          orderby t.TERM_START_DATE descending
                          select new { startdate = t.TERM_START_DATE, id = stu.STTR_STUDENT };
           TERMSSTUS = new List();
           foreach (var i in TERMSSTU)
           {
               TERMSSTUS.Add(new TERMSTU() { Id = i.id, startdate = i.startdate });
           }

   ```
       var graduation = from a in _DB.ACAD_CREDENTIALs
                        where a.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE != null
                        where a.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE < DateTime.Today
                        orderby a.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE descending
                        select a;

       GRADUATIONS = new List<Graduation>();
       foreach (var i in graduation)
       {
           GRADUATIONS.Add(new Graduation() { Id = i.ACAD_PERSON_ID, ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE = i.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE });
       }
   }
   public List<TERMSTU> givestu()
   {
       return TERMSSTUS;
   }
   public List<Graduation> givegrad()
   {
       return GRADUATIONS;
   }
   ```

   }
2. **I modified the function to take the two queries**

   ```
   public static bool ContinuingEducation(string v, List<TERMSTU> t, List<Graduation> g)
   {
       var term = (from stu in t where stu.Id == v select stu).FirstOrDefault();
       var grad = (from gradu in g where gradu.Id == v select gradu).FirstOrDefault();
       return term.startdate > grad.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE.Value.AddDays(-14);
   }
   ```

This method has more code to write, but it saves allot of time when the program has to go through 3,000 records or so.

Comment: Does each `stu` have a unique `Id`? Does each `gradu` have a unique `Id`? If they do, you should store them in a `Dictionary` rather than a `List` to get a **dramatic** speed up.

Comment: In your `ContinuingEducation` method, you should also consider what your code should do if either `term` or `grad` is null. The code, as is, will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `Count` is inefficient, since you need to query the database extra times (once to get the `Count`, once to get the `First`). The below code change will remove the need to get the `Count`.

Change:

```
if (graduation.Count() > 0 && TERMSSTU.Count() > 0)
{
    if (TERMSSTU.First().startdate > graduation.First().ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE) // the problem is here
        return true;
}
return false;
```

to:

```
var grad = graduation.FirstOrDefault();
var term = TERMSSTU.FirstOrDefault()

if (grad == null || term == null)
    return false;

return term.startdate > grad.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE;
```

**Note that even after making this change, the `FirstOrDefault` will still likely be slow. To fix this, you should run a `SQL Trace` to see what SQL is being generated. Then look to [add indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299217/how-can-i-optimize-this-sql-query-using-indexes) / optimise the query.**

Comment: Adding to this answer: the reason why the `First` is slow compared to the `Count` is that the `First` needs to execute the `order by` to ensure that it is getting the first element based on the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Try Code

```
public static bool ContinuingEducation(string v)
{
     var TERMSSTU = (from t in _DB.TERMs.AsQueryable()
                    join stu in _DB.STUDENT_TERMS_VIEWs.AsQueryable()
                    on t.TERMS_ID equals stu.STTR_TERM
                    where v == stu.STTR_STUDENT
                    orderby t.TERM_START_DATE descending
                    select new { startdate = t.TERM_START_DATE }).FirstOrDefault();
     var graduation = (from a in _DB.ACAD_CREDENTIALs.AsQueryable()
                     where v == a.ACAD_PERSON_ID
                     orderby a.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE ascending
                     select a).FirstOrDefault();

    if (graduation==null  || TERMSSTU==null)
         return false;

     return TERMSSTU.startdate >graduation.ACAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem is not in `First` call but in your query. It is evaluated when you call `First`.

You should rewrite you code to use less queries: eq you can join both queries on the `v` parameter and then get the result and check it's dates. It will result in a single query.